# Keep usb device attached when screen is turned off

Tags: android

I need to keep a usb device attached when screen is turned off (e.g by pressing the power button).

Currently if I turn off the screen the `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` broadcast is received and I can also see `UsbDeviceConnectionJNI: close` in logcat. I have tried using a **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** but the behavior is still the same.

How do I keep a USB host device attached when the device screen is turned off?

Comment: We have this same situation and do not see detached. We do work w/ USB when the screen is off. You might want to think if there's something else at play here that's causing the detach.

Comment: After your USB device is attached do you unregister the broadcast receiver? I currently keep the broadcast receiver because there are certain actions to be performed when the device gets detached.

Comment: No we do not unregister. There are plenty of places where we register in the manifest.

Comment: I have searched my code and there's nowhere I'm explicitly sending a ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED broadcast. I suspect it's coming from the system.
I've also established that my code is the one actually closing the connection when I receive this broadcast, so I've disabled this functionality and I'm just ignoring this detached broadcast now.